# Open .PLY file with Python (WITHOUT Open3D module)

Tags: python, open3d

I am dealing with .ply files in Python. As first instance I was using Open3D to open:

```
import open3d as o3d


filepath= "sample.ply"
pcd_read = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(filepath)
```

Then converting points into a n-by-3 matrix:

```
import numpy as np


points_matrix = np.asarray(pcd_read.points)
```

Doing some experiments about making a standalone executable from my files it looks that including Open3D increases a lot the dimensions, therefore - since my only use of Open3D would be to open point cloud -  I was looking for a solution in order to open them autonomously.
By opening sample.ply with a text editor I found these like these header:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment VCGLIB generated
element vertex 32727
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
element face 0
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
[...]
```

or

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment Created by Open3D
element vertex 39163
property double x
property double y
property double z
end_header
[...]
```

Doing some research I found out that to open binary little endian I would need to decode them using something like:

```
import numpy as np


file_data = np.fromfile(filepath, dtype=">f")
```

But I'm having difficulties slicing correctly the file_data.

Comment: You need to either use Open3D or write your own PLY file parser to do this... what problems do you have specifically in doing this?

Comment: By using `file_data = np.fromfile(filepath, dtype=">f")` I am able to convert the file into a long ndarray but then I don't know how I should proceed, if there is some particular label that indicates where the data starts or how to reshape the vector.

Comment: You might be interested in using https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile